# Easiest way to remove rows based on specific column conditions when grouped by class in R?

Tags: r

This question is after making developments from feedback in my post here: [How to remove specific rows with conditions across data when data is grouped by class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117980/how-to-remove-specific-rows-with-conditions-across-data-when-data-is-grouped-by/67118172?noredirect=1#comment118638080_67118172) but I ran into a new problem.

My data frame:

```
structure(list(group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("GAD", 
"NAC", "SP"), class = "factor"), age = c(22, 37, 19, 59, 45, 
54, 19, 21, 19, 21, 25, 18, 18, 19, 20, 18, 19, 20, 19, 22, 28, 
19, 65, 20, 18, 19, 18, 18, 56, 25, 18, 27, 20, 27, 18, 55, 19, 
26, 18, 46, 62, 25, 19, 18, 19, 23, 28, 20, 29, 18, 37, 18, 46, 
18, 23, 26, 49, 59, 43, 20, 46, 35, 18, 54, 25, 48, 26, 27, 27, 
43, 29, 41, 43, 29, 19, 18, 19, 30, 27, 44, 46, 65, 36, 29, 38, 
26), worry = c(17, 18, 18, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 25, 27, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 30, 31, 32, 34, 34, 36, 37, 40, 42, 42, 43, 44, 45, 45, 
46, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 50, 53, 53, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 
59, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 62, 64, 66, 67, 67, 67, 
68, 68, 68, 69, 69, 70, 71, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 
75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 78, 80, 80, 80, 80), incor_Cz = c(0.905655679, 
-5.972279231, -0.441464378, -7.768101371, -0.068112561, -5.9488735, 
4.917631564, 3.560398459, 3.62044852, 3.208378382, 6.383463977, 
3.101797215, 2.928925966, 10.92697216, 9.674200152, -0.430347693, 
5.768622107, 4.361622622, 3.814244831, 10.6478174, 4.621914209, 
4.015470126, -2.990363994, 10.28108226, 4.330419384, 4.777957595, 
-2.351932712, -0.86237015, -3.487416819, -5.954685457, 0.082161102, 
2.69205892, -2.195755315, 10.44202624, 1.727674592, 4.310826532, 
8.370135468, 9.529998174, 11.84098752, 2.449555383, -5.489426436, 
6.802779597, 0.217815002, 10.06140598, 2.626799279, -3.593214611, 
-2.486217625, -11.32397897, 7.154051703, 6.901286517, 3.504033222, 
-6.316759194, 10.70866173, -8.972840718, 4.533894362, -11.77410765, 
0.236432185, -3.721355061, -0.440954973, -15.3296636, -0.320463156, 
-7.644082526, 5.732567823, -0.659948993, 5.331566103, -1.161087095, 
4.699510759, 5.038408832, -3.100193429, 0.712125907, 10.28751091, 
-0.926246126, 8.789326896, -2.642870899, 1.412052899, 1.266241584, 
9.31459946, -0.827073637, 0.302046533, -1.002243048, -3.36313534, 
3.96444658, -1.022874301, 14.25621138, -1.30046704, 2.30875538
), corr_Cz = c(6.483764554, 0.17135543, 6.839731626, 3.502085263, 
5.464570162, -3.898580751, 8.486522854, 5.193051225, -1.077336305, 
2.253276067, 6.734594272, 1.008001519, 2.752022253, 10.15283381, 
10.67605329, 0.054572416, 3.298597911, 12.50543853, 9.012508794, 
9.900038662, 6.509256106, 2.953717593, 2.437522863, 11.26964708, 
5.085908835, 5.054000349, -0.376062125, 1.992393525, 6.489963996, 
6.411416639, -0.65324494, -0.572531358, -3.488881215, 10.5146121, 
8.979631825, 5.883346362, 8.835913808, 9.126806683, 13.09475723, 
0.469198649, 1.605589433, 7.74512423, 1.330835368, 8.015422928, 
6.225187747, 0.008224673, 2.714404145, 1.245554826, 2.277742942, 
1.753820412, 5.114288415, 0.285880059, 10.42432614, -2.280815921, 
2.527486235, -6.767570127, 3.347916611, 3.135211125, -1.282160871, 
-2.483906663, 10.96091046, -0.026853122, 9.81999986, -0.541655651, 
7.566954252, 1.971577596, 3.272944482, 9.747471161, 12.14564621, 
5.960042605, 7.480088326, 8.952888624, 6.302918576, -0.881073076, 
3.246495941, 9.763856362, 1.720188523, 3.033841316, 12.46009515, 
2.589991797, 3.187351241, -3.483036943, 3.088361102, 4.390436546, 
0.046362569, 2.779881841)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 68L, 
69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
85L, 86L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 97L, 99L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 105L), class = "data.frame")
```

Essentially, I calculate the mean and standard deviations by class via the `aggregate()` function

```
mean_list <- aggregate(data$corr_Cz, list(data$group), FUN = mean)
sd_list <- aggregate(data$corr_Cz, list(data$group), FUN = sd)
```

But then I run into this problem where I would need to make three separate dataframes for each group so I can find the data which are 3 or more standard deviations away from the mean and remove them

```
GAD_only <- data[data$group == 'GAD',]

GAD_only$standard_deviations_corr <- lapply((GAD_only$corr_Cz-3.498088)/4.033308, FUN = abs) #number in the numerator is mean subtracting from the corr_Cz value. The denominator is standard deviation.

GAD_only <- GAD_only[!(GAD_only$standard_deviations_corr >= 3),] #removes values of 3 or more
```

The problem is - I had another method using the `group_by()` which did this is one step and created a `dflist` which I can then use `do.call(rbind, dflist)` to assign a new dataframe with the rows I needed to remove now gone.

My global environment will get bogged up especially as my data grows and becomes more confusing. I will have to created three separate dataframes, remove the values I need to remove, and then bind them into one dataframe again. I could do it like this, but I was wondering if there is a way I can do this in one or two steps instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the process by using `dplyr` without creating additional temporary dataframes.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(mean_val = mean(corr_Cz), 
         sd_val  = sd(corr_Cz), 
         standard_deviations_corr = abs((corr_Cz - mean_val)/sd_val)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(standard_deviations_corr <= 3)
```